# Kubectl Export is deprecated . Any alternative

Tags: kubernetes, export, deprecated

I'm looking for a way to export a yaml file from a deployed component but without the cluster specific information.

```
kubectl get MYOBJECT --export -o yaml > my.yaml
```

but since "export" is now deprecated (since 1.14 and should normally disappear in 1.18 (didn't find it in changelog), what would be an alternative ?

thanks

Comment: `kubectl get ... -o yaml | kubectl neat`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no consistent way to do this since there is no overall guidelines about defaulting and other live data clean up. That is why it was deprecated. You should keep your source files in git or similar.

Answer (score 15):

Using JQ does the trick.

```
kubectl get secret <secretname> -ojson | jq 'del(.metadata.namespace,.metadata.resourceVersion,.metadata.uid) | .metadata.creationTimestamp=null'
```

produces exactly the same JSON as

```
kubectl get secret <secretname> -ojson --export
```

Comment: here example with more cleanup and change name. `kubectl get secret my-source-secret -n -my-source-ns -ojson | jq 'del(.metadata.namespace,.metadata.resourceVersion,.metadata.uid,.metadata.selfLink,.metadata.managedFields,.metadata.annotations."kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration") | .metadata.creationTimestamp=null | .metadata.name="my-new-secret-name"' | kubectl apply -n target-ns  -f -`

Answer (score 14):

Finally an easy to use tool has been created: https://github.com/itaysk/kubectl-neat

You could easily install all it as a kubectl [krew](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew) plugin:

```
kubectl krew install neat
```

Usage as well is pretty simple

```
kubectl get pod mypod -o yaml | kubectl neat
```

Comment: oh man, kubectl-neat is aptly named. it's super neat. makes a HUGE difference when updating IAC. thanks for adding that link!

Comment: except I do not see `status` key.

Comment: Works as it should. The purpose is to show the manifest without runtime state.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use YAML input / output, you can use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).

This did the trick for me, add or remove filters as appropriate for you:

```sh
kubectl get secret "my_secret" -n "my_namespace" --context "my_context" -o yaml \
    | yq d - 'metadata.resourceVersion' \
    | yq d - 'metadata.uid' \
    | yq d - 'metadata.annotations' \
    | yq d - 'metadata.creationTimestamp' \
    | yq d - 'metadata.selfLink'
```

Comment: might as well delete the entire metadata and do a write of a new value

Comment: add this line :

```
 | yq d - 'metadata.managedFields'
```

Comment: If you are like me and got yq 4 the new syntax is as follows:

kubectl get secret "my_secret" --namespace="my_namespace" -o yaml \
    | yq e 'del(.metadata.resourceVersion)' - \
    | yq e 'del(.metadata.uid)' - \
    | yq e 'del(.metadata.annotations)' - \
    | yq e 'del(.metadata.creationTimestamp)' - \
    | yq e 'del(.metadata.selfLink)' - \
    | yq e 'del(.metadata.managedFields)' - \

Answer (score 7):

Currently the one option is to do `-o yaml` or `-o json` and remove the unnecessary fields

Comment: Indeed doing 

`kubectl get MYOBJECT -o yaml > my.yaml`

instead of 

`kubectl get MYOBJECT --export -o yaml > my.yaml`

seems to produce almost the same output except for a few additional fields which should not do any harm.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to make use of the annotation field `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration` which holds the resource initial applied configuraiton without auto-generated fields.

Example:

```
kubectl get <resource kind> <resource name> -o yaml | \
yq r - 'metadata.annotations."kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration"'
```

Comment: I get `Error: unknown command "r" for "yq"`. I think you meant `yq e`?

Comment: maybe we are using different yq versions, that's what I meant: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/v/v2.x/read

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using `yq` v4.x you can do the following to get what you need:

```
kubectl get <resource> -n <namespace> <resource-name> -o yaml \
  | yq eval 'del(.metadata.resourceVersion, .metadata.uid, .metadata.annotations, .metadata.creationTimestamp, .metadata.selfLink, .metadata.managedFields)' -
```

Comment: this is the real neat (y)

Comment: That works like a charm. One field is missing `.metadata.generation`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above input, I created a short at our fubectl project: https://github.com/kubermatic/fubectl/pull/58

hopefully it helps also for others:

```
kget-ex RESOURCE > export.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Export is deprecated in latest version of Kube or Openshift. We can directly do it like below

```
 oc get virtualservices -o yaml > project.yaml
 oc get routes -o yaml > project.yaml
```

Comment: The second line would overwrite the output of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

solution with ZERO dependencies to any 3rd-party tool:

```bash
kubectl -n $ns get [resourcetype] [resourcename] |\
 sed '/^  uid: /d; /^  resourceVersion: /d; /^  creationTimestamp: /d; /^  selfLink: /d; /^status:$/Q;'
```

##### Note: Works only with individual resources

Answer (score -2):

Use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to fetch the "last-applied-configuration" field (json format), then convert it to yaml.

```
 kbprod get deploy xxx -o yaml | yq e '.metadata.annotations."kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration"' | yq -p json -o yaml
```