# Exporting PersistentVolumes and PersistentVolumesClaims from Kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

On GKE I created a `statefulset` containing a `volumeClaimTemplates`. Then all the related `PersistentVolumesClaims`, `PersistentVolumes` and `Google Persistent Disks` are automatically created:

```
kubectl get pvc
NAME                           STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
        76m
qserv-data-qserv-worker-0      Bound    pvc-c5e060dc-88cb-4630-8229-c4b1fcb4f64b   3Gi        RWO            qserv          76m
qserv-data-qserv-worker-1      Bound    pvc-5dfffc24-165c-4e2c-a1fa-fa11dd45616f   3Gi        RWO            qserv          76m
qserv-data-qserv-worker-2      Bound    pvc-14aa9a63-fae0-4328-aaaa-17db2dee4b79   3Gi        RWO            qserv          76m
qserv-data-qserv-worker-3      Bound    pvc-8b701396-42ab-4d15-8b68-9b03ce5a2d07   3Gi        RWO            qserv          76m
qserv-data-qserv-worker-4      Bound    pvc-7c49e7a0-fd73-467d-b677-820d899f41ee   3Gi        RWO            qserv          76m
```

```
kubectl get pv
pvc-14aa9a63-fae0-4328-aaaa-17db2dee4b79   3Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound      default/qserv-data-qserv-worker-2      qserv                   77m
pvc-5dfffc24-165c-4e2c-a1fa-fa11dd45616f   3Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound      default/qserv-data-qserv-worker-1      qserv                   77m
pvc-7c49e7a0-fd73-467d-b677-820d899f41ee   3Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound      default/qserv-data-qserv-worker-4      qserv                   77m
pvc-8b701396-42ab-4d15-8b68-9b03ce5a2d07   3Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound      default/qserv-data-qserv-worker-3      qserv                   77m
pvc-c5e060dc-88cb-4630-8229-c4b1fcb4f64b   3Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound      default/qserv-data-qserv-worker-0      qserv                   77m
```

```
gcloud compute disks list                                                                                                                   
NAME                                           LOCATION       LOCATION_SCOPE  SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
...
pvc-14aa9a63-fae0-4328-aaaa-17db2dee4b79       us-central1-c  zone            3        pd-balanced  READY
pvc-5dfffc24-165c-4e2c-a1fa-fa11dd45616f       us-central1-c  zone            3        pd-balanced  READY
pvc-7c49e7a0-fd73-467d-b677-820d899f41ee       us-central1-c  zone            3        pd-balanced  READY
pvc-8b701396-42ab-4d15-8b68-9b03ce5a2d07       us-central1-c  zone            3        pd-balanced  READY
pvc-c5e060dc-88cb-4630-8229-c4b1fcb4f64b       us-central1-c  zone            3        pd-balanced  READY
```

Is there a simple way to extract PVC/PV yaml file so that I can re-create all PVs/PVCs using the same Google Disks. (This might be useful to move the data to a new GKE cluster in case I delete the current one, or to restore the data if somebody remove accidentally the PVCs/PVs)

```
kubectl get pv,pvc -o yaml > export.yaml
```

Above command does not work because there is too much technical fields set at runtime which prevent `kubectl apply -f export.yaml` to work. Would you know a way to remove these fields from `export.yaml`

Comment: I'd reckon this guides could help you: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd, https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots. As far as I am aware for exporting the `PVC` and `PV` definitions, some kind of scripting would be necessary (to export only needed information). Have you considered using backup tools for such situations (migration, deletion)?

Comment: Yes I have investigated in Velero, but it is complex to install, especially on GKE, so I think I'll go toward some scripting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked in the question:

> Is there a simple way to extract PVC/PV yaml file so that I can re-create all PVs/PVCs using the same Google Disks.

Some scripting would be needed to extract a manifest that could be used without any hassles.

I found a StackOverflow thread about similar question (how to export manifests):

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Kubectl export is deprecated any alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392206/kubectl-export-is-deprecated-any-alternative)*

> A side note!
>
> I also stumbled upon [kubectl neat](https://github.com/itaysk/kubectl-neat) (a plugin for `kubectl`) which will be referenced later in that answer.
>
> As correctly pointed by the author of the post, `kubectl neat` will show the message at the time of installation:
>
> > **WARNING: You installed plugin "neat" from the krew-index plugin repository.**
> >
> > **These plugins are not audited for security by the Krew maintainers.**
> > **Run them at your own risk.**

I would consider going with some backup solution as more a viable option due to the fact of data persistence and in general data protection in case of any failure.

From backup solution side you can look here:

- *[Portwortx.com: How to migrate stateful application from one gcp region to another with portwortx kubemotion](https://portworx.com/how-to-migrate-stateful-applications-from-one-gcp-region-to-another-with-portworx-kubemotion/)*
- *[Velero.io](https://velero.io/)*

`PV`'s in `GKE` are in fact `Google Persistent Disks`. You can create a snapshot/image of a disk as a backup measure. You can also use this feature to test how your migration behaves:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Compute: Docs: Disks: Create snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Compute: Docs: Images: Create delete deprecate private images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images)*

---

**Please consider below example as a workaround.**

I've managed to migrate an example `Statefulset` from one cluster to another with data stored on `gce-pd`.

Once more, I encourage you to check this docs about using preexisting disks in `GKE` to create a `Statefulset`:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Persistent Volumes: Preexisting PD](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd)*

Assuming that you used manifest from official Kubernetes site:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Controllers: Statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)*

You can migrate it to another cluster by:

- **Setting the `ReclaimPolicy` to `Retain` on each `PV` used**. <-- IMPORTANT
- Using `kubectl neat` to extract needed manifests
- Editing previously extracted manifests
- Deleting the existing workload on old cluster
- Creating a workload on new cluster

#### Setting the `ReclaimPolicy` to `Retain` on each `PV` used

You will need to check if your `PV` `ReclaimPolicy` is set to `Retain`. This would stop `gce-pd` deletion after `PVC` and `PV` are deleted from the cluster. You can do it by following Kubernetes documentation:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Administer cluster: Change PV reclaim policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/)*

More reference:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Persistent Volumes: Dynamic provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#dynamic_provisioning)*

#### Using `kubectl neat` to extract needed manifests

There are many ways to extract the manifest from Kubernetes API. I stumbled upon `kubectl neat` [here](https://github.com/kubermatic/fubectl/pull/58#issuecomment-729546861). [kubectl-neat](https://github.com/itaysk/kubectl-neat) will remove some of the fields in the manifests.

I used it in a following manner:

- `$ kubectl get statefulset -o yaml | kubectl neat > final-sts.yaml`
- `$ kubectl get pvc -o yaml | kubectl neat > final-pvc.yaml`
- `$ kubectl get pv -o yaml | kubectl neat > final-pv.yaml`

> Disclaimer!
>
> This workaround will use the names of the dynamically created disks in `GCP`. If you were to create new disks (from snapshot for example) you would need to modify whole setup (use preexsiting disks guide referenced earlier).

Above commands would store manifests of a `StatefulSet` used in the Kubernetes examples.

#### Editing previously extracted manifests

You will need to edit this manifests to be used in newly created cluster. This part could be automated:

- `final-pv.yaml` - delete the `.claimRef` in `.spec`

#### Deleting the existing workload on old cluster

You will need to release used disks so that the new cluster could use them. You will need to delete this `Statefulset` and accompanying `PVC`'s and `PV`'s. Please make sure that the `PV`'s `reclaimPolicy` is set to `Retain`.

#### Creating a workload on new cluster

You will need to use previously created manifest and apply them on a new cluster:

- `$ kubectl apply -f final-pv.yaml`
- `$ kubectl apply -f final-pvc.yaml`
- `$ kubectl apply -f final-sts.yaml`

---

As for exporting manifests you could also look (if feasible) on Kubernetes client libraries:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Using API: Client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/)*

Comment: Thanks! I was aware that `kubectl neat` + removing the `claimRef` would work but I'd like to have something more accurate, because `kubectl neat` is marked as "USE AT YOUR OWN RISK" when you install it, that's why I have implement a PVC/PV export with `client-go` to have a fine-grained control. I'll provide the script here when it'll be polished. Otherwise I have followed all your other advices related to `persistent disks` management.

Comment: @FabriceJammes Yes, you are correct. My bad that I didn't include the "Use at your own risk" message. Will update it. Glad that you figured out the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example script which replace `kubectl neat` and manual edit of the manifest files (removal of `.spec.claimRef` field) in order to export the mapping between PVCs,PVs and Google Persistent Disks.

https://github.com/k8s-school/skateful/blob/stackoverflow/main.go

How to use it:

```
git clone https://github.com/k8s-school/skateful.git
git checkout stackoverflow
# Requirements: go >= 1.14.7 and a kubeconfig file
make
./skateful
```

it will create a `pvc-pv.yaml` file that can be applied to any new  GKE kubernetes cluster in order to attach the existing Google Persistent Disks to new PVCs/PVs.